# combine multible commands in one run one of them is find

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I want in one line a command to use find to get a file name from a txt file  , search for it , and play it then after closing the video I need to run a certain script

I managed the first part but when it comes to run the script after closing the video it fails

this is the command I use to play the video

```
find /Videos/ -name $(grep -vm 1 OK '~/content') -exec vlc {} \;
```

I need to run a script after I close it so I modified it

```
find /Videos/ -name $(grep -vm 1 OK '~/content') -exec vlc {} \; sh '~/close.sh'
```

but it fails with this message it think it's wrong and bash handle it as one of the options of `find`

so how in one line i can combine a command after `find` that is not related to the search result of find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus:

```
find /Videos/ -name $(grep -vm 1 OK '~/content') -exec vlc {} \; ; sh '~/close.sh'
```

The second `;` is not escaped and will be treated by `bash` as terminating the `find` command.

---

When you do

```
find /Videos/ -name $(grep -vm 1 OK '~/content') -exec vlc {} \; sh '~/close.sh'
```

The `;` is escaped (note the `\` before it) and is used to end the command for the `exec` option, so anything after that continues to be part of the overall `find` command. So when you need to run a command after the `find` (and anything it runs) exits, you need to add a second `;` to tell `bash` that whatever follows is a new command.

Comment: There's no second ; - perhaps the user edit it out?

Comment: @Jan no, I'm telling OP to add a second `;`.

Comment: Oh, I see. But is it what the OP wants? I imagine the script shall run after every invocation of the first -exec...

Comment: @Jan I think OP wants to run the script when the `find` command exits.

Comment: yes this is the correct answer for this question  , but as i used it before and failed i checked the command and found find it self fails in getting the file name if it contains spaces and works fine if i replaced the spaces with ? .. can you please advise about that or i should open a new question ?

Comment: @FatMind You're talking about the filename given in `~/content`? Tried wrapping the process substitution in quotes? `-name "$(grep ...)" `?

Comment: yes that's what I did , many thank for your help